# Scalar derivative of vector norm

Tags: derivatives, vectors, normed-spaces

Can someone check my math here? I feel like this should be a very simple problem, but I can't seem to confirm this by searching.

What is the derivative of a vector norm? I'm referring to the usual Euclidean norm (2-norm)

$$s = \|\mathbf{x}\| \text{ where }\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ and } \mathbf{x} = f(t)$$

Is it correct that:

$$\dot{s} = \frac{\mathbf{x}\cdot \dot{\mathbf{x}}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}$$

The dots are referring to time derivatives $\left( \dot{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x} \right) \\$

If the above is not correct, how to I calculate $\dot{s}$ from $\mathbf{x}$ and $\dot{\mathbf{x}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are indeed correct:
$$ s=||\vec{x}||=\sqrt{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}} \\ \frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x})}{2\sqrt{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}}}=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\vec{x}}{s}
$$

Comment: Great, thanks. I was able to derive this, but then I confused myself and was surprised that I couldn't confirm this derivation by searching. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\f#1#2{\lr{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Here's a straightforward derivation using *differentials*
$$\eqalign{
s^2 &= x\cdot x \\
2s\,ds &= 2x\cdot dx \\
ds &= \f{x\cdot dx}{s} \\
\dot s &= \f{x\cdot \dot x}{s} \\
}$$